# Anytone 878 UV Commercial license?

Tags: united-states, legal, anytone

This radio has a commercial mode but no where that I can find does it describe which commercial license. Looking at the tag under the battery...

FCC ID T4KD887UV
https://fccid.io/T4KD878UV
...so part 22 and part 90?

Part 90 is [Commercial, public safety and Government](https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/bureau-divisions/mobility-division/private-land-mobile-radio-services), but what is Part 22 exactly? Trying to figure this out is like looking for a sentence in War and Peace.

Comment: Part 90 is Private Land Mobile Services (not Amateur Radio, which is Part 97).  That is, police, fire, taxi, tow trucks, railroads, etc.

Comment: Uh... then this ISN'T a Ham HT ?! OH! Wait. The part 97 license won't be in the radio because I'm the one with the part 97 license, not the radio.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on "22" in the web page you linked to, you're taken to [this page](https://ecfr.io/Title-47/pt47.2.22), which reveals that Part 22 is CFR ›  Title 47 ›  Volume 2 ›  Chapter I ›  Subchapter B ›  [Part 22 - Public Mobile Services](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-22).

So I think the answer that you were looking for is that Part 22 is Public Mobile Services.  I was surprised to see that Wikipedia doesn't have an article about Public Mobile Services.  [47 CFR § 22.99](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/22.99) defines Public Mobile Services as, "Radio services in which licensees are authorized to offer and provide mobile and related fixed radio telecommunication services for hire to the public."

Comment: Cell phones being probably the most well known Public Mobile Service, but also covers paging and a few other services.

Comment: Any ideas what that is about? Maybe the GPS?

Comment: Nobody is allowed to transmit on GPS except the govt.

Comment: If you're asking why Part 22 rather than Part 90, I have no idea.  It has nothing to do with the GPS because the radio doesn't transmit on the GPS band, and FCC type certification isn't required for receivers.